# How can I reference a pillar item using contents_pillar from ext_pillar : file_tree in masterless mode?

Tags: salt-stack

I'm using salt in standalone minion mode, ie just one instance without master. The `/srv/secrets/` folder contains secret files like the `id_rsa` file and others. In a pillar state file I have the following

```
ext_pillar:
  - file_tree:
      root_dir: /srv/secrets/
      follow_dir_links: False
      keep_newline: True
  - some_other_var: some_other_value
```

When I do `salt-call saltutil.refresh_pillar` and `salt-call pillar.items` I get the following

```
[INFO    ] Determining pillar cache
[INFO    ] Determining pillar cache
local:
    ----------
    ext_pillar:
        |_
          ----------
          file_tree:
              ----------
              follow_dir_links:
                  False
              keep_newline:
                  True
              root_dir:
                  /srv/secrets/
        |_
          ----------
          some_other_var:
              some_other_value
```

**My question**: How can I reference eg the contens of the `id_rsa` file using `contents_pillar`?

When I try `salt-call state.apply` with

```
ssh_private_key:
  file.managed:
    - name: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
    - contents_pillar: ext_pillar:id_rsa
```

I get `Pillar ext_pillar:id_rsa does not exist`. When I use `ext_pillar:some_other_var`, `contents_pillar` works and is set to `some_other_value` (as specified above). So I guess the whole pillar system is working, but I am referencing it wrongly. I also tried `ext_pillar:file_tree:id_rsa` without success.

My setting:

- Debian jessie
- salt-call 2015.8.8.2 (Beryllium) (installed using the bootstrap script in [Salt Masterless Quickstart](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/quickstart.html))

Comment: You need to put your `ext_pillar` config in your master config instead of as a pillar file. Also `ext_pillar` is not supported in masterless mode, see https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/development/external_pillars.html

Answer (score 2):

The files provided with `file_tree` are exposed as pillar data, without any difference.
To get the file `tree_root/keys/id_rsa`, you'd use:

  `- contents_pillar: keys:id_rsa`

For my need, I add a root folder named `files` to be sure I don't create conflicts between `file_tree` files and other pillar values.

Also, in the current implementation, you have to place your files inside a directory structure for nodegroups or hosts.

In `ext_root`:

```
nodegroups/servers/ {files}
nodegroups/stations/ {files}
nodegroups/.../ {files}
hosts/host1/ {files}
hosts/host2/ {files}
hosts/.../ {files}
```

If you want all hosts to get some files, you have to create a nodegroup that contains all hosts, and then put your files in: `nodegroups/all/`. But then, you have other issues, like not being able to get yours files with `salt-ssh` as nodegroups aren't supported here (grains not available). And I think this is the case with standalone salt too.

So I guess that, in your case, you could place your files in `hosts/{minion_id}`. `minion_id` being your hostname.

Comment: I opened an issue to add this ability: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/32978